# In sqlalchemy, how do I get a query that matches all rows in a table such that no row in another table links to it?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, "event" and "event_exception". Table "event" has a (boolean) column "regular" that indicates whether the event is to occur regularly every year or not. Table "event_exception" has a column "event_id", a column "year" and a (boolean) column "occurs".

The data is to be interpreted this way:

- Some events occur regularly every year, but sometimes they exceptionally don't, which is being encoded by an "event" row with "event.regular == True" and an "event_exception" row with "event_exception.occurs == False" for every year where the event exceptionally is omitted.
- Some events don't occur regularly, but sometimes they exceptionally do. This is being encoded by an "event" row with "event.regular == False" and an "event_exception" row with "event_exception.occurs == True" for every year where the event exceptionally occurs.

How can I write a query that matches all events that will occur this year?

My guess was something like

```
session.query(Event, EventException).filter(Event.id==EventException.event_id)
.filter(EventException.year==current_year).
filter(or_(
    and_(Event.regular==1, EventException.occurs==0, having(count(EventException)==0)),
    and_(Event.regular==0, EventException==1, having(count(EventException)>0)
))
```

, but I'm not sure if the `having` clause can be used within an `and_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`. Anyway, neither of them is necessary in this case, what is needed is `EXISTS`. Assuming you already have a SQLAlchemy relationship defined for `Event.exceptions`, the following expression should work:

```
session.query(Event).filter(or_(
    and_(
        Event.regular == True,
        ~Event.exceptions.any(and_(
            EventException.year == current_year,
            EventException.occurs == False,
        )),
    ),
    and_(
        Event.regular == False,
        Event.exceptions.any(and_(
            EventException.year == current_year,
            EventException.occurs == True,
        )),
    ),
))
```

and generate SQL like the following:

```
SELECT event.*
FROM event
WHERE
    (
        event.regular = true
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM event_exception
            WHERE
                event.id = event_exception.event_id
                AND event_exception.year == :year
                AND event_exception.occurs = false
        )
    )
    OR
    (
        event.regular = false
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM event_exception
            WHERE
                event.id = event_exception.event_id
                AND event_exception.year == :year
                AND event_exception.occurs = true
        )
    )
```

EDIT: the first condition should use `NOT EXISTS` instead

Comment: I still didn't have the time to try it, but your solution sounds very logic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the answer, I just wanted to note a few things as I recently had some problems with boolean queries under sqlalchemy...

- You should do the boolean comparisons as '== True' and '== False'.  MySQL stores Boolean as 1/0, but PostgreSQL and others store as true/false, and so does Python.  SqlAlchemy converts as needed, but when you're looking at someone else's code... well that looks like an INT comparison and not a BOOL.   It'll just be easier for other people who have to look at this in the future.  .
- Depending on the SQL storage engine and column defaults, you might not get the results you want.  If there are NULL values allowed in the set, your comparisons won't match up.  You'll get the results you want with a search like :

  `Event.regular.op('IS NOT')(True)`

  `Event.regular.op('IS')(False)`

  `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.coalesce( Event.regular , False ) != True`
  `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.coalesce( Event.regular , False ) == False`

In the first bit of code, we search for items that are not True -- which would be both False and NULL.  The result set for `regular != True` only contains `False` items; the result set for `regular IS NOT True` contains `False` and `Null`

In the second bit of code, the database will coalesce `Null` values to `False` before the comparison.

You might not need to do these comparisons, but on the chance you do and your results are not looking right, this is probably why.

Comment: I really glad someone put an answer to tell the difference between `IS ` and `==`. It solves the mystery I had. Thanks!